# close browser upon test error - protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

i'm running protractor tests. if angular is not found or some exception is thrown, the test finishes however, the browser is not closed. this is a problem when running protractor in CI.

i tried using the `onCleanUp` function in the config file with no success.

any ideas how to close the browser after tests finished?

thanks you

Comment: Did you figure this out?